# Unable to connect Stack Overflow profile with Careers 2.0 one

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs

I want to connect to my [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) profile with my Stack Overflow one. But, after clicking on `Request an Invitation`, I receive message: `An invitation request has already been made for this email address`. What is wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

At some point in the past we must have already sent you an invite. They're only good for a couple of weeks. I went ahead and sent you another one.

Comment: Can't this be automated so that when the system identify the request was sent more than [x] days ago it won't show the error message but rather send a new invite? It will save you some precious time... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard At some point we're going to revamp the invite process, but it's in the infamous 6-8 week time frame. As far as saving me time? Eh, it take me 30 seconds to resend an invite.

Comment: Fair enough, will poke you within 6-8 weeks then! :D